# Removing (glued?) P trap

Tags: plumbing, sink, bathroom-fixtures, vanity

I don't have a lot of DIY knowledge, so I apologize if the solution seems obvious.

I'm trying to replace a bathroom vanity. Tutorials for removing a P trap mention removing two nuts, but I only see one on mine.

The trap seems to be stuck on the other pipe - possibly glued. Do I need to cut it, and if so where should it be cut?

Thanks in advance!

[image: P trap/wall]

Comment: There are tools(reamers) to save some parts like couplings/elbows, but for a one off job would just cut and replace, parts are not that expensive.  Cut at an edge of a joint, so can attach the new pieces.  Will probably need to account for missing length.

Comment: Make sure that you get a proper slip-joint p-trap to install. It'll make any future maintenance (possibly done by you) much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it appears that your trap has been glues in place instead of utilizing slip connections. You'll have to cut off the old one. Use a hack saw or single handle one. I would start out by cutting the pipe right after the joint on the right of your picture. You might have to cut off more later but you always want to avoid cutting off too much. Get your new trap and fittings and see how they'll all fit together. Then adjust the drain pipe accordingly. If you have cut off more, cut off no more than the last fitting in your picture. You want to save that pipe out of the wall for your slip fittings to the new trap.

Comment: Would emphasize what @JACK said regarding fitment of new trap and fittings... Make sure you dry fit the P-trap and all fittings before using ABS cement to avoid cutting further into the pipe towards the wall. This is especially true when your first few drain changeouts.